# i was new to apache storm would like to know key difference between storm 1.1 and storm 2.0?

Tags: apache-storm

I was trying to find up any major difference between storm 1.1 and storm 2.0.
Is there any difference while setting up cluster for either of the versions?
(read on official website about new Java-based implementation but has anyone seen any difference between these two versions).

Comment: Please describe in more detail what kind of answer you're looking for. I could link you to the 2.0.0 changelog, or to the release announcement, but I'm not sure that's what you're asking for.

Comment: i have to shift from storm 1.1 to storm 2.0 , but i have been asked to make sure there is a significant difference in terms of time etc.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to reading the changelog at https://www.apache.org/dist/storm/apache-storm-2.0.0/RELEASE_NOTES.html, you can look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-2306?focusedCommentId=16291947&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16291947 for some performance numbers. You can also run your own benchmarks of course.